# for each car click I need to show the car name in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- for each car click I need to show the car name in the browser.

  - I thought I will use e.target.innerText similar to js in react
  - but its not working.
  - using map I was able to iterate the array.
  - but I am not sure how to achieve click event.
  - am I using useState correclty to set the car names
  - providing my code snippet and sanbox below.

  https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-ptolemy-su53h

```or-tag-here
  function App() {
    const [carbrand, setCarBrand] = useState();
    let cars = ["honda", "toyota", "bmw"];
    let eachCarName = cars.map(name => {
      console.log("name--->", name);
      let carDiv = <div>{name}</div>;
      return carDiv;

      //return name;
    });

    console.log("eachCarName--->", eachCarName);
    const eachCarClick = e => {
      console.log("eachCarClick--->", e);
      console.log("eachCarClick e.target.innerText--->", e.target.innerText);
    };

    // const setCarBrand = eachCarName;
    // const carbrand = eachCarName;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1 onClick={eachCarClick(event)}>{eachCarName}</h1>
      </div>
```

Comment: just ```<h1 onClick={eachCarClick}>{eachCarName}</h1>``` .... do not invoke the eachCarClick function in the html, but define it as the eventhandler. The event is then automatically inserted as the first param of the function when its invoked on click

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that will do the job for you

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [carbrand, setCarBrand] = useState();
  let cars = ["honda", "toyota", "bmw"];
  let eachCarName = cars.map(name => {
    console.log("name--->", name);
    let carDiv = <div>{name}</div>;
    return carDiv;

    //return name;
  });

  console.log("eachCarName--->", eachCarName);
  const eachCarClick = e => {
    console.log("eachCarClick--->", e);
    console.log("eachCarClick e.target.innerText--->", e.target.innerText);
  };

  // const setCarBrand = eachCarName;
  // const carbrand = eachCarName;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={eachCarClick}>{eachCarName}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here's a codesandbox doing what you need https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-cloud-fwj6h

Comment: hey I tried your code, I am getting error https://codesandbox.io/s/late-sound-smr1n

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues here, but functionally the biggest thing is there is no `innerText` attribute - `e.target` will return the HTML element, you need to get the `value` or `id` or whatever attribute you need off of it. In my example below i called it ID

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/spring-mountain-1v8873222-wpl0d

code:

````
function App() {
  const [carbrand, setCarBrand] = useState('');
  let cars = ["honda", "toyota", "bmw"];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {cars.map(carName => <h1 id={carName} onClick={e => setCarBrand(e.target.id)}>{carName}</h1>)}
      {carbrand && <p>you clicked: {carbrand}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}```

I opted for doing the mapping inline for simplicity.  There's no real issue either way but stylistically, for something so simple this would be my preference.
````

Comment: hey when I click each value I am seeing undefined in alert, can you tell me how to shows the values in the browser

Comment: try this: https://codesandbox.io/embed/spring-mountain-1v8873222-wpl0d

Comment: I forgot to fork the sandbox - i'll edit the above.  If this helped you please upvote or mark correct.  Thank you!

Comment: you will see the value in the browser after click - it's the line that says `{carbrand && <p>you clicked: {carbrand}</p>}

Comment: hey suppose I have ten thousand cars, is it good to attach an event handler to each car or to the outer div, can you tell me good approach and how to achieve, since now we are attaching for each car

Comment: if you're clicking on each car you'd need the handler on each car.  Again, if this answer helped, please mark it as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

I thinh you have some problem with onClick here my example code

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-field-3wj2x

code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [carbrand, setCarBrand] = useState();
  let cars = ["honda", "toyota", "bmw"];
  let eachCarName = cars.map((name, index) => {
    return (
      <h1 onClick={e => eachCarClick(e)} key={index}>
        {name}
      </h1>
    );
  });

  const eachCarClick = e => {
    setCarBrand(e.target.innerText);
  };

  // const setCarBrand = eachCarName;
  console.log(carbrand);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{eachCarName}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: hey I am seeing the values in the console but how to shows those values in the browser, instead of passing click in h1 can we pass in outer div, which is best approach, providing my updated code here  and why your passing e before onclick `onClick={e => eachCarClick(e)}`, can you explain it will help me to understand   https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-ptolemy-su53h